# MarionetteJS & CompositeView - How to render custom table headers

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm new to MarionetteJS and love it.  I've created an ItemView and CompositeView to show the values within a collection.  This is great, but I want to render custom field/column headers.  I've done this using Backbone.Collection and using _.each(item.keys(), function(key){...  I cannot does this with MarionetteJS since I am using an ItemView for each Row.

I've tried using appendHTML, but am having difficulty accessing the collection.  Here's what I got so far:

```
...
render: function () {
    var template = "<% _.each(item.keys(), function(key){%><th><%= key %></th><%})%>";
    this.$("thead").html(_.template(template, {
        item: this.collection.models[0]
    }));
},
appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
    collectionView.$("tbody").append(itemView.el);
},
...
```

This is not working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store extra data in this compositeView and then use it in template. Allow me to use CoffeeScript below.

Step 1: Get the data and store it in a context variable say `this.headers`

```
initialize: ->
  @headers = @collection.last().attributes.keys
```

Step 2: Make the data available in template using built-in `templateHelpers`

```
templateHelpers ->
  view = @ # Use this line because context will change below
  headers: ->
    view.headers
```

Step 3: Show it in template with simple iteration. I'll use Handlerbars for example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Records</th>
      {{#each headers}}
        <th>{{this}}</th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
    <!-- Display itemViews here-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I understand your approach.  The use of .last() and templateHelpers are patterns I was not aware of.  On the other hand, I'm still stumped.  The sub ItemView renders the tbody just fine.  In the parent CompositeView, it seems 'this.headers = this.collection.last().keys()' is not working.  I stepped through the code using dev tools and it seems .last() is not a valid method for this.collection.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoseLopez, the collection should be able to use `last()` which is an underscore method borrowed by Backbone. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods The reason may be the collection is not ready yet, please check if collection is valid at that moment. If not, you need to manually assign collection as `@collection = options.collection` (options as initialize argument) before querying the last one.

Comment: By the way, `keys` should not work directly on a model instance. Instead it should be on `attributes` property. I've updated the answer.